# Fortigate 5.4 "(Rcode=-810, Hcode=-1004) (-20199)"

Tags: windows-7, vpn

I have a Windows 7 64 bit laptop with Forticlient 5.4.2. It was working well to connect to my work VPN but since yesterday I am getting the following error.

> An abonormal condition is detected.
>   You need to reboot your PC to fix this issue.
>   (Rcode=-810, Hcode=-1004) (-20199)

I have restarted the machine several times but the error still persists. I have tried everything I could think of. Other laptops in my office can connect with the same user name and password but it is failing on this one only. 
Please assist me how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Fortinets SSLVPN-Client 4.0.2332 and our FortiGate with FOS6.2.1 since I have tried different Windows 10 "Onboard" SSL-VPN-Tools even from Fortinet itself.  They did not behave as expected and therefore have been removed. Since then I ran into the same issue like you. I have tried to "repair" the SSLVPN-Client via the "Program and Features" menu of Windows10 (1903) and it worked instantly again - even without a reboot AND without Admincredentials! *like*
Hope this is helpful for sombody.